# var_dump on a json_decode variable PHP

Tags: php, json, var-dump

quick question, im doing a var_dump on a json_decode variable in php like this:

```
var_dump(json_decode($some_Variable, true));
```

And, since $some_Variable is quite a long json string, it shows up like this in my browser:

```
array (size=10)
      0 => 
        array (size=14)
          'gameId' => int 1290161341
          'invalid' => boolean false
          'gameMode' => string 'CLASSIC' (length=7)
          'gameType' => string 'MATCHED_GAME' (length=12)
          'subType' => string 'RANKED_SOLO_5x5' (length=15)
          'mapId' => int 1
          'teamId' => int 200
          'championId' => int 55
          'spell1' => int 4
          'spell2' => int 14
          'level' => int 30
          'createDate' => float 1390601626963
          'fellowPlayers' => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          'statistics' => 
            array (size=44)
              ...
      1 => 
        array (size=14)
          'gameId' => int 1291665162
          'invalid' => boolean false
          'gameMode' => string 'CLASSIC' (length=7)
          'gameType' => string 'MATCHED_GAME' (length=12)
          'subType' => string 'RANKED_SOLO_5x5' (length=15)
          'mapId' => int 1
          'teamId' => int 200
          'championId' => int 236
          'spell1' => int 4
          'spell2' => int 21
          'level' => int 30
          'createDate' => float 1390674755052
          'fellowPlayers' => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          'statistics' => 
            array (size=41)
              ...
```

(Yes its league of legends, im using Riot API (http://developer.riotgames.com/) to write a small application). As you can see, for instance the index 'fellowPlayers' doesnt show me the actual values in it, it just shows "..." and same for statistics, how can i do so it shows the all thing in every index?

Comment: Are you using Xdebug?

Comment: You have xdebug installed. http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#var_display_max_depth

Comment: Im using wamp server. Dont really know what Xdebug is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `json_decode` returns an array, try

```
$arJson = json_decode( $strJson, true );
var_dump( $arJson[ 0 ] );
```

Since you are printing each element, there is chance that the result may not be obfuscated.

Comment: this worked, since its just for view reasons, i can just dump the variable in the index that i want so it shows the whole thing. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently using [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/), a PHP debugging extension that (among other features) [overloads the native `var_dump()` function](http://xdebug.org/docs/display) with its own fancy version. You can tweak its settings or simply disable it by setting the `xdebug.overload_var_dump` directive to `false`.

In `php.ini`:

```
xdebug.overload_var_dump=0
```

In regular PHP code:

```
<?php
ini_set('xdebug.overload_var_dump', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just dump the JSON? JSON is more readable and if you `echo` it, it won't be cut off. It won't be formatted nicely, but you can easily copy/paste it into an editor that will format it nicely (many IDE's can do this). Firefox's Scratchpad development tool can do it too.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at the end line of your php.ini, if you are using xampp C:\xampp\php\ **php.ini**

```
; with sane limits
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 10
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 256
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 1024 

; with no limits
; (maximum nesting is 1023)
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1 
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
```

Its work 100% for me